# Is there a way to track if a user checks in from an application?

Tags: facebook

I am writing an mobile website that I want users to check in at the current physical location and for the website to get verification of this being done. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Graph API Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) has a connection called `checkins` which you can send an Http post to to check the user in at that location.  It requires [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) of user_checkins and I think publish_stream.

Comment: I am trying to read if they checked in, not actually write a check in